# Simple History To Remember Last Command Executed

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, char

I am trying to simulate a shell terminal in c, one of the functionalities is to be provide a simple memory to remember the **last** **command** executed. So how I am going about is:

- Every time the user enters a command (String) the string is saved in a file (command_histroy.txt)
- If the user enters "r" (command=="r"), the terminal calls the function **getSavedCommand()**, as I am only saving only one command so my function is:

  ```
   char* getSavedCommand(void){
    char cmd[1000];
     int i=0;
     char* filename = "files/command_history.txt";

       FILE* file = fopen(filename,"r");
         if(file!=NULL){
          int c;
            do{
              c = fgetc(file);
              cmd[i]=c;
              i++;
            } while (c != EOF);
          }else{
              puts("Error Reading file");
        }
       return cmd;
      }
  ```

So as in the file "command_history.txt", there is only one line stored, I reassumed that it would return this one line in an array of chars. To test I printed the results:

```
    cmd = getSavedCommand();
    printf("|%s|",cmd);
```

And the result I get is:

```
   arj@arj-Inspiron-1545:~/projet$ ./a.out 
   |ls -l /home/arj
   �|
   arj@arj-Inspiron-1545:~/projet$
```

What I want is:

```
         |ls -l /home/arj|
```

I think the EOF is creating the problem. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

One of the problem is you don't null terminate your array before returning. You need something like `cmd[i] = '\0'` at the end.

One more serious problem is you are returning a pointer to an object that is destroyed when the function returns. `cmd` object has automatic storage and is destroyed at the end of the function. Use `malloc` to allocate the array, or pass a pointer to the array as the argument of your `getSavedFunction`.

Comment: @ouaj
so i should do 
  char* cmd = malloc(sizeof(1000));

Comment: @arj that's a solution, and then you need to `free(cmd)` when the array is no longer used. Passing a pointer to the allocated array is actually more elegant.

Comment: @ouaj  i added '\0' at the end of the array, but it still gives me the same output

Answer (score 0):

This functionality (plus command line edition, and a slew of other goodies) is the whole point of GNU [`readline`](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline) (if on Linux, it is probably provided as a prebuilt package) or its BSD clone [`libedit`](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libedit) (probably already available on BSD Unix).